# Plot $\mathrm{Re}(z)$ vs. $\alpha$ for $z^2+2 \alpha z +1=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

What features the following plots would have?

Give: $$z^2+2 \alpha z +1=0$$

(A) Plot $\mathrm{Re}(z)$ vs. $\alpha$ for $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$

(B) Plot $\mathrm{Im}(z)$ vs. $\alpha$ for $\alpha \in (0,  \infty)$

(C) Plot $\mathrm{Im}(z)$ vs. $\mathrm{Re}(z)$  for $\alpha \in (0,  \infty)$

Use key words such as straight line, asymptotic curve, circle or half circle, etc. to describe the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^2 + 2\alpha z + 1 = 0$
$ \Rightarrow \mathscr D = 4\alpha^2-4 = 4(\alpha^2-1)$
$ \Rightarrow z = \frac{-2\alpha \pm 2 \sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}{2} = -\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1}$.
For $|\alpha| \geq 1 : Re(z) = -\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1}, Im(z) = 0$.
For $|\alpha| < 1 : Re(z) = -\alpha, Im(z) = \pm \sqrt{1- \alpha^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

First, solve the equation - $\displaystyle z_{1,2}=\frac{-2\alpha\pm\sqrt{4\alpha^2-4}}{2}=-\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}$.

If $|\alpha|\ge 1$, then you have only real solutions, thus the real part is $z$ and the imaginary part is $0$. In other case, I would write $z_{1,2}=-\alpha\pm{i}\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. From these you can find that $Re(z)=-\alpha$ and $Im(z)=\pm\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$. Do you know how to plot it?

Answer (score 0):

$$z=-\alpha\pm\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}=-\alpha\pm i\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}$$

A) The half ($x<0$) of the ellipse $x^2+2\alpha x+1=0$ until $\alpha=1$, then the oblique line $x=-\alpha$.

B) $0$ until $\alpha=1$, then a branch of the hyperbola $y^2-\alpha^2=1$.

C) The real line segment from $0$ to $-1$, then a branch of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1 (x<0$).